# Service Broker limit in SQL Server

Tags: service-broker

As mentioned in the [Link](https://www.codemag.com/article/0605061/SQL-Server-2005-Query-Notifications-Tell-.NET-2.0-Apps-When-Critical-Data-Changes) below,

For client-side applications, query notification users should not exceed ten concurrent users , in SQL Server 2005.

What is the maximum number of concurrent users allowed while using query notification in  SQL 2008,2017 and above?

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this by saying you should be using a supported version of SQL Server. SQL Server 2008 ended Extended support in 2019 [Microsoft Lifecycle Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/?products=sql-server)

I haven't found any basis for the claim of not exceeding 10 concurrent users. Seems like that is a personal recommendation.

I also haven't found any error messages referencing the limit on the number of queues (or internal tables that are used for the queues).

Anecdotally we were using more than 100 concurrent users for SQL Dependency since SQL Server 2016 and additional Service Broker queues

I recommend testing your required number of queues on your current system.